# syntax error when using greater than less than in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
User.where(is_individual: true)
  .includes(:visitor)
  .where(visitors: { finished: false })
  .where(visitors: { step > 2 })
```

I am trying to get the out of the above query but it is returning an error

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>)
...visitors: { step > 2 })
```

But if I do as below then it works.

```
User.where(is_individual: true)
  .includes(:visitor)
  .where(visitors: { finished: false })
  .where(visitors: { step: 2 })
```

So the query doesn't work with greater than operator.

I even tried below query and it still doesn't work

```
User.where(is_individual: true)
  .includes(:visitor)
  .where(visitors: { finished: false })
  .where(visitors: { "step > ?", 2 })
```

Comment: When working with Ruby DSLs, remember that it's still Ruby. For example, a `{ ... }` hash literal is always composed of keys and values – either as `key: value` or `key => value`. Anything else will result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error you're running into is due to the structure of the argument being passed to the last `where` clause - `{ "step > ?", 2 }` is not a valid Ruby object.

If using Ruby 2.6 or greater, you can leverage its [endless range syntax](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-6-adds-endless-range) to construct the query:

```rb
User
  .includes(:visitor)
  .where(is_individual: true, visitors: { finished: false, step: 3.. })
```

If using Ruby 2.5 or below you can produce the same query using `Float::INFINITY`:

```rb
User
  .includes(:visitor)
  .where(is_individual: true, visitors: { finished: false, step: 3..Float::INFINITY })
```

Alternatively, you can pass a SQL string to `where` to query on the included model (you'll need to reference the associated table via [references](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references)):

```rb
User
  .includes(:visitor)
  .references(:visitors)
  .where(is_individual: true)
  .where(visitors: { finished: false })
  .where("visitors.step > ?", 2)
```

You can also explicitly use `joins` in this case to retrieve the desired results:

```rb
User
  .joins(:visitor)
  .where(is_individual: true)
  .where(visitors: { finished: false })
  .where("visitors.step > ?", 2)
```